# state is not managed correctly in react functional component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-state

I'm trying to work on a react page that has 3 states: View: 0, Edit and Add
the page state keeps track of current record id and the state page is in. Here are the rules.

1. record id can change only if page is in view mode
2. if page enters Edit/Add mode then unless user is out of that mode, record id must not change and the page state stays as it is

here is my code to achieve the same

```
interface IPageManager{
  id: number,
  mode: Modes,
  grid: {page: number,  size: number},
  
  setId(id: number): void,

  enterAddMode(): void,
  enterEditMode(teamId: number): void,
  enterViewMode(id?: number): void
  debug(msg: string):void
}


type PageStateType = {
  grid: {page: number,  size: number},
  id: number,
  mode: Modes
}

function usePageManager(): IPageManager {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ grid: {page: 1, size: 10}, id: 0, mode: Modes.View } as PageStateType)
 
  const isEditing = () => state.mode === Modes.Add || state.mode === Modes.Edit
  const change = (teamId?: number, mode: Modes= Modes.View)=>{
        if(!isEditing())
            setState(current=>produce(current, x=>{
              if(teamId)
                x.id = teamId
              x.mode = mode
            }))    
        }
  
 

  const manager: IPageManager = {
    get id() { return state.id }
    , get mode() { return state.mode }
    , get grid() { return state.grid }
    , setId(id: number) {
      setState(previous => produce(previous, x => { x.id = id }))
    }
    , enterAddMode() {  change(undefined, Modes.Add)  }
    , enterEditMode(teamId: number) { change(teamId, Modes.Edit) }
    , enterViewMode(id?: number){
      if(!isEditing()){
        setState(previous=>produce(previous, x=>{
          x.mode = Modes.View
          if(id)
            x.id = id as number
        }))
      }
    }
    , debug(msg: string){
      const mode = state.mode===Modes.View? 'View': state.mode===Modes.Edit? 'Edit':'Add'
      trace(`${msg} - {id:${state.id}, mode:${mode}}`)
    }
  }  

  return manager
}



export function TeamsPage() {
  const header = useMemo(() => <PageHeader title="Teams Management" />, [])
  const manager = usePageManager()
  
  manager.debug('page') // reflects correct state

  const { data }= useQuery('teams', async () => await getTeams(manager.grid.page, manager.grid.size))
  const view =(id: number)=>{
    manager.debug(`before`) // manager state always at initial state
    if(manager.mode===Modes.View) //always true since default is View 
    {     
      manager.setId(id)
      manager.debug(`after`)  // manager state always at initial state
    }
  }
  
  const listing = useMemo(() => {
    const { rows, count } = data ?? { rows: [], count: 0 } as TeamSummary  
    const t0 = (
      <Listing
        data={rows}
        page={manager.grid.page}
        size={manager.grid.size}
        count={count}
        onSelect={(arg) => view(arg.id) }
        onAdd={() => manager.enterAddMode()}
        onEdit={(arg) => manager.enterEditMode(arg.id)}
      />)

    return t0
  }, [data])

  useEffect(() => {  // if the data is updated, set the recordId to the first record in grid
    const { rows, count } = data ?? { rows: [], count: 0 } as TeamSummary  
    if (rows && rows.length>0) {
        const first = _.first(rows)
        if (first)
          manager.setId(first.id)
    }    
  }, [data])

  // it renders either an editor or a viewer, does not mantain any state on its own. depends on props only  
  const detail =<RecordBar id={manager.id} mode={manager.mode} getRecord={getTeam} emptyRecord={() => emptyTeamDetailResponse} />

  return (
    <Layout
      summary={listing}
      detail={detail}
      header={header}
      footer={<></>}
    />
  )

}
```

In my opinion the page should work correctly but this is what I see in output
[image]

As you can see, after entering the Edit mode, page does change the current id despite the fact that if condition checks if the page is in view state or not before making any changes. To that if condition, state is always initial state even though in page it is reflected correctly.

1. is it some sort of closure problem or react issue or my coding is incorrect?
2. is it the correct way to manage the view i.e. by creating a custom hook that holds the state and returns the functions to operate on state?

Comment: Glancing throught the code, my first line of inquiry would be to move from useState to [useReducer](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-usereducer/). As a thumb rule I wouldn't use useState for deep structures. If you choose to stick with `useState` try passing a type to the generic parameter useState<IManagerState>(...

Comment: actually after much painful debugging, i was able to solve the issue by taking <Listing/> out of the useMemo() and everything worked fine as it should. What i do not understand is that why the listing events need to be bind every time that causes unnecessary rendering. it seems that if the state of parent changes, every child will re-rendered and if I use useRef then there is no way to find out if anything has changed

Comment: useReducer() should make things complicated? I don't know I never used it. just used plain redux

Comment: Good that it is working, It seems you are trying to manage complicated state inside a hook, so doing this with useState may lead to issues.  Anyhow I would try to look at react-table, I think it can provide you some of the functionality you are trying to achieve with the custom hooks. Building custom hooks which are complicated and does not have a good test coverage is prone to create bugs.